# Making user follow another user can get its twitter username

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have a button on my website which says "Follow"
When a user clicks on this button I want the following to happen:

1. Twitter login window opens
2. User enters user/password and logs in
3. User has now started following
4. That login window now closes (or a close button clicking on which closes the window) and user is back on my website and I get its twitter username through some API which user just entered so I can insert it in my database.

Is this possible?

What I want to achieve is, I want to get username of users who follow me and save them in database.

Comment: What in https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids doesn't suffice you?

Comment: Actually that may not work in my case because I want to map twitter ID with their account which is in my database. Basically this follow procedure is being done when a user logs into my website. So when a user enters his twitter user/password to login and follow me, at that exact time I want to get their twitter ID. So I guess I will have to look at link provided by Laurent below which might work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case @penartur's answer doesn't work for you, you may want to look at: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events.  Although I have to admit that I've never used it : )